# TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str' how to fix

Tags: python

```
a = 1
s = 0
print ('Enter Numbers to add to the sum')
print ('enter 0 to quit')
while a != 0:                  
        print ('Current Sum',s)
        a = input('Number?: ') 
        s = s + a
print ('Total sum: ',s)
```

how to fix that error ?

Comment: I think this is exactly the inverse of *that* question, @AmiTavory

Comment: @WayneWerner Can't say that I see why. Fundamentally, it's exactly the same problem, no?

Comment: Not *really*. I mean, fundamentally yes, they're both the `__add__` function, yet converting a string to an integer for addition is rather different than concatenating strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to convert from the string input to a number.  For instance:

```
    a = int(input('Number?: '))
```

In other news:

You can use the short-cut **+=** operator for summing **s**:

```
s += a
```

Answer (score 1):

Return type of `input()` is `str`. You have to explicitly typecast it to `int` type. `s += int(a)` will work perfectly fine.